# Autosize the outlook Custom Taskpane automatically with different screens

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, autosize, customtaskpane

I have created an outlook addin and added a custom taskpane to it

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {  
            taskpane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new UCMaster(), "Summit Service Management");
            UserControl ucmaster = taskpane.Control;
            eh = new ElementHost { Child = new WPFUCMaster(new WPFUCLogin()) };
            eh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            eh.AutoSize = true;
            ucmaster.Controls.Add(eh);
            taskpane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
            taskpane.DockPositionRestrict = Office.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;
            taskpane.Width = 460;
            taskPaneWidth = taskpane.Width;
            taskPaneHeight = taskpane.Height;
            ucmaster.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);        
            ucmaster.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            ucmaster.AutoSize = true;
            int h = ucmaster.Height;
            int w = ucmaster.Width;
            initialAddinInstance = this;
            ucmaster.BringToFront();
        }
```

here im hardcoding the taskpane width according to my screen dimensions and resolution it is looking proper.

But,in different screens im observing like the task pane is getting compressed or in any other way.

my question is how can i dyanmically change the taskpane width according to the current system screen resolution and dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

For Container controls "AutoScaleMode" should be Inherit and for Leaf Controls it should be Font.
Try this one :
ucmaster.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Inherit;
and
Make your child User control to :
ucChild.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;